# one paragraph in full width

Tags: paragraphs, width, fullwidth

I have a latex paper with 2 columns, but there is one paragraph I would like to make it to ocupy all the paper width.

Is it possible? how ?

I've tried using fullwidth with no success.

The problem is this: 
[image: equations cutted]

I want those equations to be in the center of the page.

thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome!  Please post a MWE (minimal working example), i.e. a piece of LaTeX code that can be compiled and demonstrates the problem you're having.

Comment: what's most important here is *where* this wide paragraph is to go: is it at the top of the first page, at the bottom of a page, or somewhere in the middle.  that's why a compilable (even if not working) example is needed.